# How to handle error from api request properly with RxSwift in MVVM?

Tags: swift, mvvm, error-handling, rx-swift

So, I have a button and will make an API request upon tapping it. When the API request returns an error, if my understanding is correct, the sequence will be terminated and no subsequent action will be recorded. How do I handle this properly so that I can still make another API request when tapping the button.

My thoughts are to have two observables that I can subscribe to in **ViewController** and on button pressed, one of it will print the success response and one of it will print the error. Just not quite sure how I can achieve that.

PS: In Post.swift, I have purposely set *id* as *String* type to fail the response. It should have be an *Int* type.

**Post.swift**

```
import Foundation
struct Post: Codable {
    let id: String
    let title: String
    let body: String
    let userId: Int
}
```

**APIClient.swift**

```
class APIClient {

    static func request<T: Codable> (_ urlConvertible: URLRequestConvertible, decoder: JSONDecoder = JSONDecoder()) -> Observable<T> {

        return Observable<T>.create { observer in

            URLCache.shared.removeAllCachedResponses()

            let request = AF.request(urlConvertible)
                .responseDecodable (decoder: decoder) { (response: DataResponse<T>) in

                switch response.result {
                case .success(let value):
                    observer.onNext(value)
                    observer.onCompleted()
                case .failure(let error):
                    switch response.response?.statusCode {
                    default:
                        observer.onError(error)
                    }
                }
            }

            return Disposables.create {
                request.cancel()
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**PostService.swift**

```
class PostService {
    static func getPosts(userId: Int) -> Observable<[Post]> {
        return APIClient.request(PostRouter.getPosts(userId: userId))
    } 
}
```

**ViewModel.swift**

```
class LoginLandingViewModel {

    struct Input {
        let username: AnyObserver<String>
        let nextButtonDidTap: AnyObserver<Void>
    }

    struct Output {
        let apiOutput: Observable<Post>
        let invalidUsername: Observable<String>
    }

    // MARK: - Public properties

    let input: Input
    let output: Output

    // Inputs

    private let usernameSubject = BehaviorSubject(value: "")
    private let nextButtonDidTapSubject = PublishSubject<Void>()

    // MARK: - Init

    init() {

        let minUsernameLength = 4

        let usernameEntered = nextButtonDidTapSubject
            .withLatestFrom(usernameSubject.asObservable())

        let apiOutput = usernameEntered
            .filter { text in
                text.count >= minUsernameLength
            }
            .flatMapLatest { _ -> Observable<Post> in
                PostService.getPosts(userId: 1)
                    .map({ posts -> Post in
                        return posts[0]
                    })

            }

        let invalidUsername = usernameEntered
            .filter { text in
                text.count < minUsernameLength
            }
            .map { _ in "Please enter a valid username" }


        input = Input(username: usernameSubject.asObserver(),
                      nextButtonDidTap: nextButtonDidTapSubject.asObserver())

        output = Output(apiOutput: apiOutput,
                        invalidUsername: invalidUsername)

    }

    deinit {
        print("\(self) dellocated")
    }


}
```

**ViewController**

```
private func configureBinding() {

        loginLandingView.usernameTextField.rx.text.orEmpty
            .bind(to: viewModel.input.username)
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)

        loginLandingView.nextButton.rx.tap
            .debounce(0.3, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
            .bind(to: viewModel.input.nextButtonDidTap)
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)

        viewModel.output.apiOutput
            .subscribe(onNext: { [unowned self] post in
                print("Valid username - Navigate with post: \(post)")
                })
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)


        viewModel.output.invalidUsername
            .subscribe(onNext: { [unowned self] message in
                self.showAlert(with: message)
            })
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by materializing the even sequence:

First step: Make use of `.rx` extension on `URLSession.shared` in your network call

```
func networkCall(...) -> Observable<[Post]> {
    var request: URLRequest = URLRequest(url: ...)
    request.httpMethod = "..."
    request.httpBody = ...

    URLSession.shared.rx.response(request)
        .map { (response, data) -> [Post] in
            guard let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []),
                let jsonDictionary = json as? [[String: Any]]
                else { throw ... }    // Throw some error here

            // Decode this dictionary and initialize your array of posts here
            ...
            return posts
        }
}
```

Second step, materializing your observable sequence

```
viewModel.networkCall(...)
    .materialize()
    .subscribe(onNext: { event in
        switch event {
            case .error(let error):
                // Do something with error
                break
            case .next(let posts):
                // Do something with posts
                break
            default: break
        }
    })
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

This way, your observable sequence will never be terminated even when you throw an error inside your network call, because `.error` events get transformed into `.next` events but with a state of `.error`.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, dispose bag should not exist in ViewModel according to best practices that I have came across but can't really find the source anymore.

Comment: Yeah you're absolutely right, subscriptions should be created inside view controllers, hence dispose bags are also in view controllers. I didn't mean to put step 2 inside view models. But step 1 should be inside view model

Comment: Ahh... my bad, somehow when I see viewModel, I immediately thought it was referring to ViewModel file.

Comment: This worked for me! Just curious how do I achieve same result if I want to separate the two events into two observables that I can subscribe in ViewController, like I have added in my question?

Comment: I’ll answer you in the morning :) have to sleep

Comment: I thought about it and it can be accomplished via Subjects. But it's fairly complex and compared to the approach in the answer, that has 0 benefit to it. But if you're interested, you can still try. Hint, pass a subject (e.g., PushSubject, ReplaySubject, etc...) to your network call and call `subject.onNext(...)` whenever an error occurs. And in your view controller, you can subscribe to that subject and whenever you get an event, you resubscribe to the button tap.

Answer (score 1):

So I have also found the way to achieve what I wanted, which is assigning the success output and error output into two different observable respectively. By using **RxSwiftExt**, there are two additional operators, ***elements()*** and ***errors()*** which can be used on an observable that is materialized to get the element.

Here is how I did it,

**ViewModel.swift**

```
let apiOutput = usernameEntered
            .filter { text in
                text.count >= minUsernameLength
            }
            .flatMapLatest { _ in
                PostService.getPosts(userId: 1)
                    .materialize()
            }
            .share()

let apiSuccess = apiOutput
    .elements()

let apiError = apiOutput
    .errors()
    .map { "\($0)" }
```

Then, just subscribe to each of these observables in the ViewController.

As reference: http://adamborek.com/how-to-handle-errors-in-rxswift/